# How to use like operator in sql alchemy python

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in snowflake the below lines execute successfully , but when it comes to python then it is unable to identify the statement .

issue is coming when i'am using like operator.

**SQL SCRIPT**

```html
select COUNTRY,RESPONSE_VALUE,LATITUDE,STOREID,ZIPCODE,REQUESTED_SERVICE,TENANTID,LONGITUDE,CITY,STATE,RESPONSE_ERRORS,CREATEDAT,RESPONSE FROM HEVOPROD_DB.HEVOPROD_SCH.PRDNEW_METERING where REQUESTED_SERVICE = '["store-boundary-dsp"]' and storeid is not null and latitude is not null and longitude is not null and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"message":%' and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"storeExternalId":%' and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"provider":%' and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"type":%'   limit  20;
```

**python script**

```html
try:
    start_date = input("Start_date_epoch:")
    end_date   = input("End_date_epoch:")
    type_service= '["sb-dsp"]'

    query_sb_dsp_positive = """ select COUNTRY,RESPONSE_VALUE,LATITUDE,STOREID,ZIPCODE,REQUESTED_SERVICE,TENANTID,LONGITUDE,CITY,STATE,RESPONSE_ERRORS,CREATEDAT FROM HEVOPROD_DB.HEVOPROD_SCH.PRDNEW_METERING where  latitude is not null and longitude is not null and  storeid is not null and latitude is not null and longitude is not null and TENANTID is not null and COUNTRY IS NOT NULL AND CITY IS NOT NULL AND STATE IS NOT NULL  and CREATEDAT between '"""+start_date+"""' AND
                    '"""+end_date+"""' and REQUESTED_SERVICE='"""+type_service+"""'  and length(RESPONSE_VALUE)<10 and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"message":%' and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"storeExternalId":%' and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"provider":%' and RESPONSE_ERRORS like '%"type":%' limit 50 ; """
```

Can anyone tell me where i'am going wrong ? how do i pass the %

Comment: Try to do it like this: '%type%' Let me know if it works!

Comment: '%storeExternalId:%' 

the values are present in multi json structure , stored something like "store","message"  , that'y i have passed the values in double quotes 

'%storeExternalId:%'   -> if i remove double quotes it will identify %s as a literal

Comment: You could escape the % character as %% or use r-string to avoid escaping. But even simpler for this example would be to use f-string so you can just use `'{end_date}'` etc within the string rather than concatenation (plus % is not special within f-string).

Comment: BTW - it is best to clearly state the exact error message / symptom you encounter.

Comment: there is no error , I'am not getting any results but when i run that same query on snowflake i get the response .

the issue is on passing the string after like operator like '%"storeExternalId":%'